# Is there a winforms designer for python?

Tags: python, winforms, ironpython

So I was just wondering if there was a winforms editor like this for python?

I saw that iron python exists but I doesn't have a visual editor It's just text...

Image that shows what I am looking for:

[image: Image that shows what I am looking for]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either of the following options:

- [Pygubu designer](https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu-designer) for [pygubu](https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu)
- [Qt designer](https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download) for [PyQt](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro)
- Windows Forms designer in Visual Studio and run the code using [IronPython](https://ironpython.net/).

**Example - Pass parameter from Windows Forms UI to a Python function**

Here is an example of using IronPython in a C# Windows Forms app:

1. Create a Windows Forms application.
2. Install [IronPython](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPython) nuget package.
3. Add `using IronPython.Hosting;` statement to the using statements.
4. Drop a `TextBox` on the form (textBox1)
5. Drop a `Button` on the form (button1)
6. Double click on button and add the following code for the click handler:

   ```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
       var scope = engine.CreateScope();
       //You can also load script from file
       var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(
           "def hello(name):" + "\n" +
           "    result = 'Hello, {}!'.format(name)" + "\n" +
           "    return(result)",
           Microsoft.Scripting.SourceCodeKind.Statements);
       var compiled = source.Compile();
       compiled.Execute(scope);
       dynamic hello = scope.GetVariable("hello");
       var result = hello(textBox1.Text);
       MessageBox.Show((string)result);
   }
   ```
7. Press F5 to Run the application, enter a text, and click on the button. The function will run and you will see a message box saying hello.

**Example source code**

You can download or clone the example:

- Download: [Zip](https://github.com/r-aghaei/WinFormsIronPythonExample/archive/refs/heads/master.zip)
- Repository: [r-aghaei/WinFormsIronPythonExample](https://github.com/r-aghaei/WinFormsIronPythonExample)

Comment: So is your 3rd suggestion:

- Windows Forms designer in Visual Studio and run the code using IronPython.

The same as the example you provided or is that a different example?

Comment: Same as the example.